# Bootstrap Form Helper V2.3.0 not work

Tags: css, bootstrap-form-helper

Hello I'am traing to create  language combobox with flags using  Bootstrap Form Helper V2.3.0 
So I

1. Download Bootstrap Form Helper V2.3.0  FREE Version
2. Download Bootsrap 3.0.0 (http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.0/docs/)
3. Link Jquery jquery-1.10.2

This version of jquery and bootsrap is requerd for Bootstrap Form Helper V2.3.0

Than create simple index.html page  and copy example code from documentation http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/language/#jquery-plugins

The result is EMPTY select list and no erros in console

Can some one expain me what I'm doing wrong?

Index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Form Helpers Basic Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- Bootstrap Form Helpers -->
    <link href="bootstrapformhelpers/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>

          <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
      <body>
      <!-- Example 3 -->
        <div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-languages" data-language="en_US" data-available="en_US,fr_CA,es_MX" data-flags="true">
        </div>
      <!-- Example 4 -->
      <span class="bfh-languages" data-language="en_US" data-flags="true"></span>
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"  integrity="sha256-it5nQKHTz+34HijZJQkpNBIHsjpV8b6QzMJs9tmOBSo="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Form Helpers -->
        <script src="bootstrapformhelpers/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are your css and js files being loaded (i.e. are they in the correct location according to the code?) You can check the Network tab in your browser's devtools

Comment: @McVenco in chrome is Source tab and yes they are there